# Unable to handle page breaks when I used emulateIE8 in <meta> tag

Tags: html, css

I used to print a form with many tables and in  tag I used as ". I'm facing an issue of page breaks. Previously I used only "content="IE=8", it creating problem of holding radial button in IE8. After i changed IE8 to EmulateIE8, there is no issue of radial buttons but it's not handling page breaks.
Could some one help to resolve this issue.

Thank you.